# Xcode5 get an EXC_ARM_DA_ALLIGN error

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iPhone&ipad App which runs on IOS6&IOS7, With Xcode4.6 and LLVM GCC 4.2. Howerver, after I upgrade to Xcode5 whit Apple LLVM 5.0, I try to run it on an iPhone5 with IOS7.0, the App will receive an EXC_ARM_DA_ALLIGN exception while initialising the global & static data before entering the main function.

0x693006:  vld1.64 {d8, d9, d10, d11}, [r4, :128]! thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN, address=0x27dd5824)
the value in the r4 is 0x27dd5824 which is 32bits alignment, but seems vld1.64 require a 64bits alignment, and the EXC_ARM_DA_ALLIGN comes.

My target deploy IOS is 6.0, Architectures Standard architectures(armv7, armv7s), so I am sure the Xcode should generate 32bit code for me.

Why I am getting this issue, cause my data is 32bits align already.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit :

I check the gcc version assembly code and did not found VLD1.64 called .

Edit add crash log :

Incident Identifier: 81A2A2B6-1A4C-450E-88A7-DF7F2F8E7619

CrashReporter Key:   c66d6f7407948d2a6ba1ecc45d6c9348d11a2ed7

Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2

Process:             XXXXXXXX [224]

Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/CBDF28BD-4EFA-46B9-8E94-7BFCE265541B/XXXXXXXXX.app/XXXXXXXX

Identifier:          com.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX

Version:             1.1.7 (1.0)

Code Type:           ARM (Native)

Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2013-10-24 17:08:39.263 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.2 (11A501)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN at 0x27d12914
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   myApp                   0x00756006 MEMORYxxxDEVICE::MEMORYxxxDEVICE() (xxxx.xxxx.cpp:2146)

1   myApp                   0x0073db40 *GLOBAL*_I_a (xxxx.xxxx.cpp:3042)

2   dyld                            0x2bee459e 
ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 174

3   dyld                            0x2bee46ac ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 16

4   dyld                            0x2bee1d34 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 356

5   dyld                            0x2bee1b88 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 36

6   dyld                            0x2bed8d38 dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 164

7   dyld                            0x2bedbab4 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 1748

8   dyld                            0x2bed822a dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 346

9   dyld                            0x2bed8064 _dyld_start + 60

Thread 1:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b9c8838 kevent64 + 24

1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b9170d0 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228

2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b91163e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):

```
r0: 0x27d128f8    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00038600      r3: 0x00002860

r4: 0x27d12914    r5: 0x2befb95c      r6: 0x0073db2d      r7: 0x27d128b0

r8: 0x00000204    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x000002b1     r11: 0x2befd754

ip: 0x3d7f70a8    sp: 0x27d128a4      lr: 0x00000000      pc: 0x00756006
```

cpsr: 0x40000030

Comment: http://www.galloway.me.uk/2010/10/arm-hacking-exc_arm_da_align-exception/ just google the da align

Comment: thanks but my pointer(here is 0x27dd5824) is already 32bit aligned...

Comment: The reason you didn't find vld1.64 is because it is ARM NEON code.  Can you get a stack trace out of it?  Maybe you are using the Accelerate framework?

Comment: Hi borrrden, I upload the crash log and I did not use Accelerate framework.